# read instrument file and print the waveform

Tags: python, string, list

I tried to print the sound wave, read a score.txt file from scores folder, in this case, 'piano', then I locate instrument file 'piano' in instruments folder

With a score .txt file 'score':

```
piano
|*********************|
```

And instrument file 'piano':

```
3             ---
2            /   \
1           /     \
0        ---              ---
-1                  \     /
-2                   \   /
-3                    ---
```

Note that the character after the number is a tab character('\t') and the rest of the character in the line are either spaces, slashes or dashes.

I wonder how could I print the final waveform

```
python waveform.py score
piano:
 3:             ***
 2:            *   *
 1:           *     *
 0:        ***       *       ***
-1:                   *     *
-2:                    *   *
-3:                     ***
```

Comment: What have you tried so far (presumably your `waveform.py` script) and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

For each line in the original file:

```
print(line.replace('-','*').replace('/','*').replace('\\','*'))
```

Comment: Is there any way I can add  ' :  ' into it? they should be in the final waveform

Answer (score 0):

It is not that simple to achieve the waveform by mere substitution. You shall need to identify the pattern from the original file and how and when the pattern pauses and changes in the final waveform taking into accordance the scores given for the instrument.